# How can I point to a Youtube video (site/app) on cardboard view by default?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Is there any way to link a Youtube video with the open cardboard view by default? Any URL parameter? API method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you check the [YouTube API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/), you cannot find any key word here about the cardboard. So it seems that this cardboard thing is not yet supported thru the YouTube API. I found here a [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/FPZvA0fDZt0) similar to your question and based on this, It's not a feature that exists at the moment, but it would be possible to implement.

I suggest you to create a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list?q=label:APi-YouTube) about this cardboard so that Google consider it and will add to their API.

Hope this information helps you.